# Заполнить массив содержимым другого массива

Tags: objective-c

Есть массив:

```
NSArray* array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, @4];
```

Создаю новый:

```
NSMutableArray* array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
```

И хочу заполнить его 20 позиций элементами из первого массива array1. Правильно ли я думаю, что сперва можно `[array2 addObjectsFromArray:array1];` а остальные элементы добавить через `for`?

```
for(int i =0; i<4; i++) {
[array2 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:0+i]];
}
```

Работает, но если я превышаю количество элементов первого массива (i>4) вываливается ошибка.

Comment: А насколько заполнение должно быть случайным? Есть критерии случайности?

Comment: Нет, критерий нету. Главное чтобы заполнение было содержимым первого массива.

Comment: Заполните его первым элементом массива или любым другим. Думаю, что цикл for отлично подойдёт.

Comment: Либо в цикле for случайно выбирайте ячеек второго массива для каждой ячейки первого - тогда у вас будет случайное заполнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот этот вариант

```
for(int i =0; i<20; i++) {
     [array2 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:0+(i % 4)]];
}
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо! Почему помогло %4 ?

Comment: % это оператор остатка от деления. В данном случае остаток от деления будет всегда строго меньше 4 и выхода за границы массива не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!